# Moving Android Studio folder locations [OS X]

Tags: android, android-studio

I recently moved my Android Studio project from my Library folder to my Documents folder, and when I open the project in Android Studio, none of the files come up under the Android files view. I can view them from the Project files view, but I cannot run any of the files like I used to be able to do. Do I have to import the project somehow? I looked around but I couldn't figure it out without starting a new project and putting the old files into it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good news, I was able to figure it out. Close the current project, then on the main screen click "Import Project". From there, it import your project with no issue.